# Salesforce does not show users in searches

Tags: case, user, servicecloud, global-search, find

it happens with all the users of the organization. When we search for a user or a queue, it does not show any results when they exist.

For example when I want to change a case owner, when searching for a queue or a new user, it does not find any.

[image]

another example would be from setup, I try to search for a user and it doesn't show me anything either. This problem only happens with users, cases and other information, it searches it well.
Has this happened to anyone?

Thank you very much

Comment: you can assign view setup and configuration permission.   i can see a known issue similar  to one described by you.  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003g4iQAA&title=spring-20-standard-users-are-unable-to-search-for-queues-when-attempting-to-change-record-owner

Comment: @gauravsharma 
thank you very much for your help. This morning I came across the link you pointed me to and that permission was already enabled in the profiles, so it's not my problem. If you can think of any possible solution, it will be welcome. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the site audit I had seen a change of Salesforce at 00.00, 24 hours later it has returned to work correctly without making any change. I understand it was some Salesforce update, any information I have, I will keep you posted by editing this post. Thank you very much